# Custom UITableViewCell not resizing when "Grouped" style is used

Tags: ios, ipad

I have view controller that is the "Detail" side of a SplitViewController.  It has a single control, a UITableView.  I'm loading a custom UITableViewCell.  It works fine when the "Style" is set to "Plain" (sort of ).  But when I change the style to "Grouped", the custom cell extends beyond the borders of each grouped section.

If I turn off "Autolayout" on the custom cell nib, it works.  But, I want the cell to use autolayout so that it will work the way I want on different devices.

Like I said, it "sort of" works in "Plain" style.  The problem is still there.  If I switch the orientation on the device, the detail view controller now has scroll bars on the view as a whole.  So, we really have the same spacing issue, it's just not as apparent.

I'm completely confused on this one.  I can't be the first to see this.

Comment: Could you provide some code or a picture of your nib file laying out the cell? I had a similar problem caused by a image view added as a subview to the cell. The image view did "overlay" the grouped style...

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the 'Horizontal Spacing' constraint that is automatically put on to any objects put in the UITableViewCell. Reducing the priority of this constraint, and then adding your own constraint programatically will solve the problem.

See this stackoverflow question - [Auto layout with custom UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12998672/auto-layout-with-custom-uitableviewcell).

Example of what I used to keep a Label within the bounds of the Grouped UITableViewCell. This needs to be done when the cell is created:

```
NSDictionary *dict = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_label);
[self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[_label]" options:0 metrics:nil views:dict]];
```